# Computing $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \arctan{\frac{x}{\epsilon}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I'm not exactly sure how to get started computing the limit of the improper Riemann integral

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \arctan\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)dx.$$

Using the result that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \pi/2$, is there a way to interchange the limit and the integral to get $\pi^2/4$?

Comment: dominated convergenze?

Comment: The integral is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Numerically, the limit seems to be $\frac {\pi^2}4$. I shall post something tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the dominated convergence theorem
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x} \arctan\frac{x}{\epsilon}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx.
$$
Now
$$
\int_\pi^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\,\arctan\frac{x}{\epsilon}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_\pi^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx+\int_\pi^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigl(\arctan\frac{x}{\epsilon}-\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr)\,dx.
$$
Let's stimate the second integral:
$$
\Bigl|\arctan\frac{x}{\epsilon}-\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr|=\int_{x/\epsilon}^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\le\frac{\epsilon}{x},
$$
and
$$
\int_\pi^\infty \Bigl|\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigl(\arctan\frac{x}{\epsilon}-\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr)\Bigr|\,dx\le\epsilon\int_\pi^\infty\frac{|\sin x|}{x^2}\,dx.
$$

Comment: That last integral does not converge, so I'm not sure what your result says.

Comment: This needs a little fixing. First, is it even clear that the  integrals converge? Best to look at $\int_0^b$, then let $b\to \infty.$ Second, it's easy to see the integral from $0$ to $1$ does what it should. For the integral from $1$ to $b$, do what you did.

Comment: @RonGordon but the bound does work from 1 to $\infty$ as well,  so I think this is morally correct

Comment: @RonGordon Thank you for the observation. I have fixed the argument.

Comment: Thanks @JuliánAguirre. I fixed a typo for you in the first line.

Comment: Is it $\pi/2$ missing in the first line? I guess that $\epsilon\to 0^+$ is meant.

Comment: @A.G. Thanks for the observation. Corrected.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre how did you get the second equation?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Interestingly, $arctan(x/\epsilon)-\pi/2=\arctan(\epsilon/x)<\epsilon/x$ from the series for the arctangent.  So, we could have easily bypassed the integral representation and estimate therefrom. But that works also!  +1

Comment: @Gorg If you drop the 1 in $1+t^2$, you get the upper bound $\int_{x/\epsilon}^\infty t^{-2} dx = \epsilon/x.$

Comment: @PhilipHoskins Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

I numerically computed the value of $$I_k= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \arctan\left(\frac{x}{10^{-k}}\right)\,dx$$  and obtained the following results  $$I_1=2.0946478630779095038$$ $$I_2=2.4071212109147673112$$ $$I_3=2.4590705601861920202$$ $$I_4=2.4663377878010322013$$ $$I_5=2.4672717431743382398$$ $$I_6=2.4673858619774465911$$ $$I_7=2.4673993461843410490$$ $$I_8=2.4674009018376888642$$ $$I_9=2.4674010781262894827$$ $$I_{10}=2.4674010978274761282$$ $$I_{20}=2.4674011002723396542$$ $$I_{30}=2.4674011002723396547$$ The limit is almost clearly $\frac{\pi^2}4$.

For $10\leq k\leq 100$, the plot of $\log(\frac{\pi^2}4-I_k)$ visually reveals an almost linear dependency to $k$ ($R^2=0.99999865$).

Later, to my surprize, a CAS found an explicit expression for the integral $$J(\epsilon)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \arctan\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)dx= \text{sgn}(\epsilon ) \,\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}  \,G_{2,4}^{3,1}\left(\frac{\epsilon
   ^2}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2},1 \\
 0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0
\end{array}
\right)$$ where appears the Meijer G function.

For $\epsilon >0$, a limited expansion of the above result gives $$J(\epsilon)=\frac{\pi ^2}{4}+\epsilon  (\log (\epsilon )+\gamma -2)+\frac{1}{108} \epsilon ^3 (6
   \log (\epsilon )+6 \gamma -13)+O\left(\epsilon ^4\right)$$ which almost perfectly reproduces the numerical results even for very small values of $k$.

Comment: Interesting! So does the $\log(\epsilon)$ in the first term say that the convergence is slightly worse than linear? That still seems pretty fast.

Comment: I should agree if $\epsilon$ was not very small.

Comment: Oh of course you're right. So it's better. Also,  after reading up on the G function, it appears to be quite a beast :)

Comment: @PhilipHoskins. I am sorry to disagree with you : it is not quite a beast. **It is a MONSTER**